# C#: how to define an extension method as "with" in F#?

Tags: c#, f#, extension-methods, immutability, with-statement

F# has a convenient feature "with", example:

```
type Product = { Name:string; Price:int };;
let p = { Name="Test"; Price=42; };;
let p2 = { p with Name="Test2" };;
```

F# created keyword "with" as the record types are by default immutable.

Now, is it possible to define a similar extension in C#?
seems it's a bit tricky, as in C# i'm not sure how to convert a string

```
Name="Test2"
```

to a delegate or expression?

Comment: I expect to see more of these questions as functional languages become mainstream. A common refrain will be "How can I do [some functional feature] in [my favorite language]?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static T With<T, U>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, U>> property, U value)
    where T : ICloneable {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    if (property == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("property");
    var memExpr = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memExpr == null || !(memExpr.Member is PropertyInfo))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must refer to a property", "property");
    var copy = (T)obj.Clone();
    var propInfo = (PropertyInfo)memExpr.Member;
    propInfo.SetValue(copy, value, null);
    return copy;
}

public class Foo : ICloneable {
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    object ICloneable.Clone() {
        return new Foo { Id = this.Id, Bar = this.Bar };
    }
}

public static void Test() {
    var foo = new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "blah" };
    var newFoo = foo.With(x => x.Bar, "boo-ya");
    Console.WriteLine(newFoo.Bar); //boo-ya
}
```

Or, using a copy constructor:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(Foo other) {
        this.Id = other.Id;
        this.Bar = other.Bar;
    }
    public Foo() { }
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public static void Test() {
    var foo = new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "blah" };
    var newFoo = new Foo(foo) { Bar = "boo-ya" };
    Console.WriteLine(newFoo.Bar);
}
```

And a slight variation on George's excellent suggestion, that allows for multiple assignments:

```
public static T With<T>(this T obj, params Action<T>[] assignments)
    where T : ICloneable {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    if (assignments == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("assignments");
    var copy = (T)obj.Clone();
    foreach (var a in assignments) {
        a(copy);
    }
    return copy;
}

public static void Test() {
    var foo = new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "blah" };
    var newFoo = foo.With(x => x.Id = 2, x => x.Bar = "boo-ya");
    Console.WriteLine(newFoo.Bar);
}
```

I would probably use the second one since (1) any general purpose solution is going to be unnecessarily slow and convoluted; (2) it has the closest syntax to what you want (and the syntax does what you expect); (3) F# copy-and-update expressions are implemented similarly.

Comment: is it possible to do: var newFoo = foo.With( Bar = "boo-ya"); ?

Comment: @athos: Yes, I added another (better, although not general-purpose) method.

Comment: @athos: I wish there was a copy constructor constraint (maybe `where T : new(T)`) so we could ruminate on generalized solutions to this. Perhaps as immutability gains better support in C# we will see features that make this easier.

Comment: @athos: ...in the meantime, I recommend F#. :-)

Comment: Thanks. solution (1) using MemberExpression is smart, yeah (2) is fine but yeah C# missing a copy constructor constraint; (3) supports multiple assignments is also nice to know!

Comment: @athos: I added a type parameter to the first solution to make it more type-safe.

Comment: right, to make it perfect, change propInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null); to propInfo.SetValue(copy, value, null);

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var NewProduct = ExistingProduct.With(P => P.Name = "Test2");
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public static class Extensions
{
    public T With<T>(this T Instance, Action<T> Act) where T : ICloneable
    {
        var Result = Instance.Clone();
        Act(Result);

        return Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do something like: var NewProduct = ExistingProduct.With(Name = "Test2"); ?

Comment: It's unlikely, you could, using String.Split and Reflection, do something like:
var NewProduct = ExistingProduct.With("Name='Test2'");
But you then get no compile time checking and you take a significant performance hit so I wouldn't recommend it.  A lambda expression is about as nice as you're likely to get.

Comment: agree, parsing strings and doing reflection is an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to lambda function, you can use parameters with default values. The only minor issue is that you have to pick some default value that means *do not change this parameter* (for reference types), but `null` should be a safe choice:

```
class Product {
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   public int Price { get; private set; }
   public Product(string name, int price) {
     Name = name; Price = price;
   }

   // Creates a new product using the current values and changing
   // the values of the specified arguments to a new value
   public Product With(string name = null, int? price = null) {
     return new Product(name ?? Name, price ?? Price);
   }
 }

 // Then you can write:
 var prod2 = prod1.With(name = "New product");
```

You have to define the method yourself, but that's always the case (unless you're going to use reflection, which less efficient). I think the syntax is reasonably nice too. If you want to make it as nice as in F#, then you'll have to use F# :-)

Comment: haha Tomas, you know what, I'm reading your "F# language review" right now! nice to see you here :)

Comment: Although this "With" depends on the Product Type, using parameters with default values is a smart tricky and interesting! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native ability to do this in C# short of an extension method, but at what cost? ***a*** and ***b*** are reference types and any suggestion that ***b*** is based ("with") on ***a*** causes immediate confusion as to how many objects we are working with. Is there only one? Is ***b*** a copy of ***a*** ? Does ***b*** point to ***a*** ?

C# is not F#.

Please see a previous SO question of mine as answered by Eric Lippert:

"Amongst my rules of thumb for writing clear code is: **put all side effects in statements; non-statement expressions should have no side effects.**"

[More fluent C# / .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916260/more-fluent-c-net)

Comment: hi Andleer, Eric's points are always worthy of a 2nd thought. just.. if we check the current TDD frameworks such as NUnit, there are lines similar to your question and mine... in a way i think "write code as close as natural English" has some merits there... if you think otherwise, well, we still can take this question as some quiz for fun ! :p

Comment: Athos, on a personal level I don't feel strongly about this. On a professional level, I liked Eric's answer because it allowed me to make a strong argument with my co-workers. No need to continue going around on this. Good luck!

Comment: @andleer - I think it is a fair question to ask how to get some construct similar to F#'s `with` in C#. Using this only makes sense if you're working with _immutable_ types, but that is perfectly useful approach in C# (afterall, all value types should be immutable). If the type is immutable then all your concerns are not a problem at all. Of course, when using mutable type, things become more difficult, but that's not what I think about when I see "F# record" in the question :-).

Comment: (That's why I think that George Duckett's answer isn't quite right because it is assuming that the type is mutable.)