# Can we get access to the F# copy and update feature from c#?

Tags: c#, f#, immutability

For example in F# we can define

```
type MyRecord = {
    X: int;
    Y: int;
    Z: int 
    }

let myRecord1 = { X = 1; Y = 2; Z = 3; }
```

and to update it I can do

```
let myRecord2 = { myRecord1 with Y = 100; Z = 2 }
```

That's brilliant and the fact that records automatically implement IStructuralEquality with no extra effort makes me wish for this in C#. However Perhaps I can define my records in F# but still be able to perform some updates in C#. I imagine an API like

```
MyRecord myRecord2 = myRecord
    .CopyAndUpdate(p=>p.Y, 10)
    .CopyAndUpdate(p=>p.Z, 2)
```

Is there a way, and I don't mind dirty hacks, to implement CopyAndUpdate as above? The C# signiture for CopyAndUpdate would be

```
T CopyAndUpdate<T,P>
   ( this T
   , Expression<Func<T,P>> selector
   , P value
   )
```

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://v2matveev.blogspot.com/2010/05/copy-and-update-in-c.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: how to define an extension method as "with" in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832880/c-how-to-define-an-extension-method-as-with-in-f)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done, but doing that properly is going to be quite hard (and it definitely won't fit in my answer). The following simple implementation assumes that your object has only read-write properties and parameter-less constructor:

```
class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

This slightly defeats the point, because you would probably want to use this on immutable types - but then you always have to call the constructor with all the arguments and it is not clear how to link the constructor parameters (when you create an instance) with the properties that you can read.

The `With` method creates a new instance, copies all property values and then sets the one that you want to change (using the `PropertyInfo` extracted from the expression tree - without any checking!)

```
public static T With<T, P>(this T self, Expression<Func<T, P>> selector, P newValue)
{
  var me = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
  var changedProp = (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)me.Member;

  var clone = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    prop.SetValue(clone, prop.GetValue(self));

  changedProp.SetValue(clone, newValue);
  return clone;
}
```

The following demo behaves as expected, but as I said, it has lots of limitations:

```
var person = new Person() { Name = "Tomas", Age = 1 };
var newPerson = person.With(p => p.Age, 20);
```

In general, I think using a universal reflection-based method like `With` here might not be such a good idea, unless you have lots of time to implement it properly. It might be easier to just implement one `With` method for every type that you use which takes optional parameters and sets their values to a cloned value (created by hand) if the value is not `null`. The signature would be something like:

```
public Person With(string name=null, int? age=null) { ... }
```

Comment: I'm hoping to define the record in F# so I get IStructuralEquality and IComparable for free. It bugs me I have to implement that manually in C#.

Comment: I'll try out your code with some F# records and see if it works.

Comment: great job Tomas but in c# it falls far short of let myRecord2 = { myRecord1 with Y = 100; Z = 2 }

Comment: Yes, F# records have read-only properties, but they have mutable fields with predictable (I think) name. So, you'd have to change the cloning code to iterate over fields (that should be easy - but you need to get private fields) and then "guess" the field name from the property name that you get in the expression tree. (Check how records are compiled - there is some naming scheme that should work).

Answer (score 7):

You could achieve something similar using optional arguments:

```cs
class MyRecord {
    public readonly int X;
    public readonly int Y;
    public readonly int Z;
    public MyRecord(int x, int y, int z) {
        X = x; Y = y; Z = z;
    }
    public MyRecord(MyRecord prototype, int? x = null, int? y = null, int? z = null)
        : this(x ?? prototype.X, y ?? prototype.Y, z ?? prototype.Z) { }
}

var rec1 = new MyRecord(1, 2, 3);
var rec2 = new MyRecord(rec1, y: 100, z: 2);
```

This is actually pretty close to the code that F# generates for records.

Comment: Sorry but the aim is to use F# records as they implement IStructualEquality and IComparable automatically. I want to use the F# records from C#. Big ask maybe but I'm tired of filling out all the boilerplate.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were trying to replicate records in C#. I'll leave my answer in case anyone's interested.

Comment: I think this is a sensible answer (my +1). A `With` method taking optional arguments could be added as an extension method to an F# record (more writing, but it will work faster and better :-))

Comment: This has some subtle bugs for nullable reference types though. If "null" is a valid value for the type, then it's impossible to update a type that has a value with null, seeing as it's impossible to distinguish between "this was passed in as null" and "this was not passed in"

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is stumbling upon this, I recently needed to do the same thing and was able to take @Tomas Petricek's answer and expand it to work with immutable records:

```
    public static T With<T, P>(this T self, Expression<Func<T, P>> selector, P newValue)
    {
        var me = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
        var changedProp = (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)me.Member;

        var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructors()[0];
        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name);
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var args = parameters
            .Select(p => properties.FirstOrDefault(prop => String.Equals(prop.Name,p, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            .Select(prop => prop == changedProp ? newValue : prop.GetValue(self))
            .ToArray();

        var clone = (T) constructor.Invoke(args);

        return clone;
    }
```

Usage

```
// F#
type Person = 
{
    Name : string      
    Age : int
}

// C#
var personRecord = new Person("John",1);
var newPerson = personRecord.With(p => p.Age, 20);
```